# Problem with Service using AIDL?

Tags: android, service, aidl

Here is my AIDL PlayerHandleService.aidl:

```
interface PlayerHandleService {
    void changeTextView();
}
```

The oncreate() on my Activity:
Player_Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.bindService(new Intent(this,PlayerService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

The mConnection:

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mpInterface=null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mpInterface = PlayerHandleService.Stub.asInterface(service);
    }
};
```

Now, on my activity (Player_Activity) have an TextView and I want to use method changeTextView() in the AIDL to change the content of that TextView, how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. Your activity changes its own `TextView`.

If your service wants to tell the activity to do something, you can use some sort of custom listener, or a broadcast `Intent`, or a `Messenger`, or `createPendingResult()`, or probably other techniques as well.

Comment: Can the instance of the AIDL interface in the activity return data ( I haven't tried, just asking)? I mean, if you have in the interface method of some type and return that type. I know that can be done with broadcasters, that's how I do it. Thank you.

Comment: The activity does not have an AIDL interface. The service does. Methods in an service's AIDL interface can return values to whoever bound to that service:  http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html

Comment: I understand. I mean you have the interface in the Service, and you create the instance in the activity so you can remotely control. E.g: in the interface you have `int returnsomenumber();` and you have override in the service, we know it. But in the activity you can have instance of the interface so you can remotely control the service, so can doing `myRemoteControl.returnsomenumber();` return data from the service? Sorry if I didnt express myself clearly